# Hover syntax difference

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

What is the difference between:

```
a.cvc-formsHelpText:hover {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

And:

```
.cvc-formsHelpText:hover {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

The HTML is:

```
<a class="cvc-formsHelpText" href="javascript: void(0)">
<img src="img.gif">
<span>Text.</span>
</a>
```

The first works and the second not, but both refer to `<a>` tag.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the dot. But with the dot the second block also doesn't work.

Comment: Geez, so all our answers are irrelevant now. It's entirely a specificity issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, when you're saying that the second doesn't work, is that you've omitted a dot, as BoltClock points out: `.cvc-formsHelpText`

As for the difference between the two syntaxes, the former denotes that the element must be an anchor with the class `cvc-formsHelpText`. The latter selector (provided that you include the dot that you've omitted) applies to *any* element with the class `cvc-formsHelpText`. Obviously, if only anchor elements contain that class, there will be no perceived difference in the way your website behaves.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with hover at all.

```
#id element.class:pseudo-selector {
  property: value;
}
```

That's the general syntax. The first selector works because it's selecting the `cvc-formsHelpText` class, not trying to fruitlessly target a non-existent `cvc-formsHelpText` **element**.

Answer (score 1):

a.blah defines a class for anchor tags (the "a" tag).  .blah defines a class for any tag.

Answer (score 0):

`cvc-formsHelpText` is a class. You need a "." in front of it if you want to style it.

```
.cvc-formsHelpText:hover {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cvc-formsHelpText:hover` means: an element named `cvc-formsHelpText`, hovered. For example, `<cvc-formsHelpText>`, which doesn't exist.

`a.cvc-formsHelpText:hover` means: an `<a>` tag, with class `cvc-formsHelpText`, hovered.

Answer (score 0):

The first says that all "a" tags are found that have "cvc-formsHelpHext" for the CSS "class" attribute. The second looks for tags named "cvc-formsHelpHext", which is not what you are trying to do.